# Select2 doesn't render nice, style is broken

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, render, jquery-select2

I tried to install **select2** on my project bt it doesn't render nice.
It's exactly the same issue than this link : [Select2 doesn't render properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773647/select2-doesnt-render-properly)

[image: select2]

But i don't use cdn, i work on symfony4 project (with webpack encore and yarn). I import **jquery** and **select2** like that :

*app.js*

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'select2/dist/js/select2.full';
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css';

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.select2').select2();
})
```

I also try this one :

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import select2 from 'select2';
```

*mypage.html*

```html
<select class="select2 form-control" style="width:200px;" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value=""><option>
    <option value="1">Mustard</option>
    <option value="2">Ketchup</option>
    <option value="3">Relish</option>
</select>
```

I have no error, but the render looks like nothing !

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: could you try to add the 'cdn' import style in your html to see if it works?

Comment: yes it's working, but i would like avoid the cdn. it's working with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">`. But why the import i did doesn't work ?

Comment: Do you have another `.js` files importing `.css` files that are working? Because the question is that probably, you need the css in your html, not in js. that's why it works when you load it directly in html and not in .js

Comment: and also, why to avoid `<link href=...>`?  it is the most efficient/performatic way to load a css file

Comment: Yes i'm using bootstrap3, with custom class. I have a `main.css` with all i need inside. For the js i have only one file.

Comment: I wanted to avoid just to try another way. Indeed i could used cdn, but it should work anyway :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many months i  optimized my website and i fixed this problem then i wanted to share the tip !

@CalvinNunes you were right, i imported the css in the js. Importing the css via the webpack.config.js works better.

I added this entry in *webpack.config.js*, and of course i removed the css import from my *app.js* file

```
.addStyleEntry('css/account', [
        'select2/dist/css/select2.css',
        'select2-bootstrap4-theme/dist/select2-bootstrap4.css',
    ])
```